# What is the time complexity of this while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, time-complexity

I'm computing for the time complexity of a certain while loop in C++, but I'm not sure how to do it on this specific while loop:

```
while ( scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &brown[0], &green[0], &clear[0],
    &brown[1], &green[1], &clear[1], &brown[2], &green[2], &clear[2]) == 9 ) 
{
/* Some code here */
}
```

Comment: To know this you'll have to analyze the inner workings of `scanf()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "time complexity" ?

Comment: No idea. For starters `brown` might be an instance of a class with very compex overloaded `[]` and `&` operators. Your question is too imprecise.

Comment: The frequency count of the while loop. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop will execute N times where N is equal to the number of inputs the program receives before the it gets more or less inputs then 9.  There is no way to figure out what that will be unless you know what the input will be.

Time complexity is normally used to express the efficiency of an algorithm which really doesn't pertain to this.